# Joining Multiple Tables in SQL Server 2008 causes error

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause

I am writing a query to join 3 tables, I have the following tables:

- `Apn [ID, QualHolderID, RecvDate, Barcode]`
- `QualHolder [ID, Surname, FullName, DOB, ResCountryID, Gender]`
- `Country [ID, Name]`
- `Gender [ID, Name]`

I wrote the following SQL statement to retrieve the data:

```
SELECT 
    a.QualHolderID, b.FullName, b.Surname, d.Name, b.DOB, b.ResCountryID, a.RecvDate
FROM
    dbo.Apn a 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.QualHolder b ON a.QualHolderID = b.ID 
JOIN
    dbo.QualHolder c 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Gender d ON c.Gender = d.ID 
WHERE
    b.ResCountryID = 48
```

But now I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near 'ID'.

Comment: I would recommend to use **more meaningful alias** for your tables! Just using `a, b, c` is confusing and not helpful. I would use `a` for `Apn`, `qh` for `QualHolder`, `g` for `Gender` etc. - those aliases are much clearer and more obvious to anyone reading and studying your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join `dbo.QualHolder` table two times.
Try it this way:

```
SELECT a.qualholderid, 
       b.fullname, 
       b.surname, 
       d.name, 
       b.dob, 
       b.rescountryid, 
       a.recvdate 
FROM   dbo.apn a 
       INNER JOIN dbo.qualholder b 
               ON a.qualholderid = b.id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.gender d 
               ON b.gender = d.id 
WHERE  b.rescountryid = 48
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the correct query is:

```
 SELECT a.QualHolderID, b.FullName, b.Surname, d.Name, b.DOB, b.ResCountryID, a.RecvDate
 FROM dbo.Apn a 
 INNER JOIN dbo.QualHolder b ON a.QualHolderID = b.ID 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Gender c ON b.Gender = c.ID 
 WHERE b.ResCountryID = 48
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `= b.ID JOIN` use following query and execute.

```
SELECT a.QualHolderID, b.FullName, b.Surname, d.Name, b.DOB, b.ResCountryID, a.RecvDate
FROM (dbo.Apn a INNER JOIN dbo.QualHolder b ON a.QualHolderID = b.ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo.Gender d ON b.Gender = d.ID 
WHERE b.ResCountryID = 48
```

Comment: you don't have the alias `c` defined.